# Connecting digital ground and chassis ground

Tags: voltage, capacitor, resistors, esd

I have an Ethernet connector whose chassis or shield ground I need to connect to the digital ground. I read that it is a practice that is followed in many designs.

My questions:

1. Why should they be connected together? Any reasons? What would happen if they are not connected?
2. In some designs, 100nF 50V capacitors are used to connect both the grounds. In some cases, I see 330ohm or 0ohm resistors.  In some other designs, I see both a resistor and capacitor are used in parallel to connect both the grounds. Can someone tell me the pros and cons of each connection to arrive at a good circuit connection?

Comment: There are application notes on that. Specifically ones that are about when and how to connect Ethernet chassis ground to signal ground, if it should be connected at all. Because we don't know your system or product as a whole, there can be no single correct way how to do it, or defining the pros and cons. All the methods you described are best, but the problem is, which one to choose for a given scenario. But we don't know what your scenario is.

Comment: @Justme, Could you please elaborate on these points?